# Add bouncing scroll arrow to bottom of my web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Here](http://fharding.me) is my current site, and the problem is you are supposed to scroll down, but that isn't super clear, so what I would like to add is something like what [this](http://ahoy.co.uk/) site has, a little arrow that suggests scrolling at the bottom of that div. I have looked everywhere but really cannot find a answer.

Comment: Look at the CSS for section-arrow.

Comment: @epascarello I've tried looking at the code for it and it really didn't help, I was looking for more of someone who knew how to do it without just copying the source code so they could explain and show me all the parts of it.

Comment: Uses CSS animation look at the code for bounce

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are your thoughts about how to achieve the bouncing arrow? The spirit of stackOverflow is more about "hey guys, I want to achieve this, and I tried this, but why is it behaving this way instead of that?" rather than "hey guys, how do I achieve this?"

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution using `@keyframes` and `animation`.

The `.contentDiv'` is whatever `<div>` you want the arrow to be at the bottom of. Just make sure that it has `position: relative`.

HTML:

```
<div class="contentDiv">
    <img class="arrow" src="arrowImage.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.contentDiv {
    position: relative;
}

@keyframes bouncing {
    0% {bottom: 0;}
    50% {bottom: 20px;}
    100% {bottom: 0;}
}

.arrow {
    animation: bouncing 1s infinite ease-in-out;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
}
```

And here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/ybq0h6o4/1/) example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setInterval`, in javascript, to cycle through two positions for your arrow:

[Example](http://codepen.io/jonathanrbowman/pen/bVvJvy)

UPDATE: I know this is an older question now, but if anyone comes back to it I updated the animation to use `transform` instead of `bottom`, which will give you better performance :)

Also, if you wanted to, you could set up some easy keyframes and do this without any javascript at all!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epMoxB) for you

Hope you can change the `transition` as per your need and here is nice [tutorial](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-bounce-effect/) for you

Thank you